# How to change this function, "car" got problems

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to write a function, which converts from a "normal" notation like this: "1+4*2-8" to this pre-notation: "+1-*428".

I hope you get the point here. 
Important: It must be in Strings.

What I get so far:

```
(define (converter lst )
     (let ((operand1 (car lst))
           (operator (car (cdr lst)))
           (operand2 (caddr lst)))
       (list operator
             (converter operand1)
             (converter operand2)))
  )
(infixLst->prefixLst '(1 + 2 * 3))
```

I got two problems here.

1) It's for Lists, I need it work for Strings like "1+3" and **not** '(1+3)

2) It doesn't work so far (even not for Lists), because it give me some errors regarding the "car", e.g: *car: expects a pair, given 1*

Soo starting with the List -> String change: (I know that (list is unappropriate here. As well as the other list-methods but I didnt got a better idea so far.

```
(define (infix->prefix str)
  (let ((operand1 (car str))
           (operator (cadr str)) 
           (operand2 (caddr str)))
       (list operator
             (infix->prefix operand1)
             (infix->prefix operand2)))
  )

(infix->prefix "1 + 2")
```

Comment: (I'm coding in Racket and not Scheme)

Comment: parse string to list tree is more straight.

Comment: You need to handle the base case for the recursion, where the expression is just one number.

Answer (score 1):

The normal notation  `1+4*2-8` is called infix notation.

- If you simply need to use that notation, Racket has a ready module: `(require infix)`, [here's a link to its documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/infix-manual/).
- If you want to practice writing your own infix parser, the [shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) can do that. It uses a stack to keep track of the operators in the math expression.

If you want to parse math from a string, you need to first split the string into a list of tokens (numbers and operators). Start with a `math->tokens` procedure that simply returns a list of the tokens without caring about their meaning. There are many ways to write it. Here is one:

```lisp
(define (math->tokens s)
  (let collect-tokens ((i 0) (tokens '()))
    (if (= i (string-length s))
        (reverse tokens)
        (let ((char (string-ref s i)))
          (if (not (char-numeric? char))
              (let ((operator (string->symbol (string char))))
                (collect-tokens (+ i 1) (cons operator tokens)))
              (let collect-number ((j (+ i 1)))
                (if (and (< j (string-length s))
                         (char-numeric? (string-ref s j)))
                    (collect-number (+ j 1))
                    (let ((number (string->number (substring s i j))))
                      (collect-tokens j (cons number tokens))))))))))
```

For example, `(math->tokens "+1-*428")` returns the list of tokens `(+ 1 - * 428)`. Now you can apply the shunting-yard algorithm to that list.